# How to get current file and line number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to implement a log function like this:

```
def mylog(str)
   puts __FILE__, ":"__LINENO__, ":", str  # Here how to get __FILE__ and __LINENO__ is my question.
end
```

When I call `mylog`:

```
mylog 'hello' # say I call this in my.rb line 10
```

I expect output:

```
my.rb:10:hello
```

Please help give right implementation of `mylog` function.

Comment: And an aside, it is `__LINE__` that returns the current line (not `__LINENO__`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to use `caller`

```
def mylog(str)
  caller_line = caller.first.split(":")[1]
  puts "#{__FILE__} : #{caller_line} : #{str}"  
end
```

You'll probably want to know the file from which `mylog` was called too...

```
def mylog(str)
  caller_infos = caller.first.split(":")
  puts "#{caller_infos[0]} : #{caller_infos[1]} : #{str}"  
end
```

Comment: This works, but is not the best. Using `caller` is old fashioned.

Comment: For future readers yes, but for now I didn't want to assume Ruby 2.0

Comment: `caller_line=caller[0].split(":")[1]; puts "#{__FILE__}:#{caller_line}:#{str}"  ` FYI, you can traverse the call stack by incrementing the zero in this example to 1, 2, etc.

Answer (score 16):

Using `caller` is old-style. Rather, use `caller_locations`.

```
def mylog(str)
  caller_locations(1, 1).first.tap{|loc| puts "#{loc.path}:#{loc.lineno}:#{str}"}
end
```

Comment: Dose caller_locations require certain Ruby version?

Comment: Yes. It was introduced in Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 11):

The correct variable to get line number is `__LINE__`, so the proper implementation of your function would be

```
def mylog(str)
 puts "#{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__}:#{str}"  
end
```

Edited so the output matches yours

Comment: If is the OP's fault to have mislead you for using `__FILE__`, but that gives the file and the line where that `puts` method is written.

Comment: Ahh yes, guess I jumped on this too quickly without fully understanding what he wanted.

Comment: For clarity, comments are regarding "Function Definition" vs "Function Call" location.

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question, but is useful since google brings people here who want to know that.